# Isometry group vs. Symmetry group

Tags: group-theory

Is there a difference between the isometry group and the symmetry group? Obviously the first one implies the existence of a metric but if we have a simple pentagon, are both groups isomorphic to $D_5$ or do we need to differ here?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the definition of symmetry group. In the context of ornament groups and crystallographic groups we certainly have have the following definition. For a Euclidean vector space $E$, a *symmetry* of a set $M$ in $E$ is an isometry $s\colon E\rightarrow E$ satisfying $s(M)=M$. It follows that all symmetries of $M$ form a subgroup $\operatorname{Sym}(M)$ of the isometry group $\operatorname{Isom}(E)$.